# Action Chooser between Chrome and Maps

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a latitude and longitude in my app and wanna show that position using another app like google maps or chrome browser. Using google Maps I can do it by creating intent like  -

```
String geoUriString = getResources().getString(R.string.map_location);
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);
Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
startActivity(mapCall);
```

Or if I do it by chrome browser then Its possible by creating intents like -

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

But I need to create Action Chooser only between Google Maps and Chrome Browser. Users will select app according to their choice from my app. How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom buttons for the user to choose between the two options,

Add this to your layout file

```
  <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:fadeScrollbars="true"
      android:fadingEdge="none"
      android:isScrollContainer="true"
      android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

       <LinearLayout
           style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/transparent"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/chrome"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@color/transparent"
               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/chrome_icon"
               android:drawablePadding="1px"
               android:focusable="true"
               android:gravity="bottom|left|center_vertical|top"
               android:text="Chrome Browser"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/maps"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="fill"
               android:background="@color/transparent"
               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/maps_icon"
               android:drawablePadding="1px"
               android:focusable="true"
               android:gravity="bottom|left|center_vertical|top"
               android:text="Google Maps"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

       </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>


//* then add the click listeners to your code.
//* Chrome
Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chrome);
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.HorizontalScrollView01);
    scrollView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //* add your code to start chrome
  }
});
//* maps
Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.maps);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.HorizontalScrollView01);
    scrollView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //* add your code to start maps
  }
});
```